# finding matched string with grep does not return the matched value

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the below code to get the matched value from grep function in perl , but it always returns a value of 1 instead of returning the matched value.

```
use strict;    
use warnings; 

my @capture = "err=\"some value\""; 

if(my @matched_string = (grep(/\berr\b/, @capture) || grep(/\bwarn\b/, @capture))){
   print "@matched_string";
}
```

How can i get the matched value.

Comment: If I use my @matched_string = (grep(/\berr\b/, @capture) only  , it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OR (`||`) imposes the *scalar context* on the first (left) [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) call.  So it returns the number of times it matched, which is then evaluated for truth.  If it matched anything that number evaluates as true, so that number is returned by `||`. Otherwise you get the other list, or an empty list if that one doesn't have a match either.

I take it that you want to get all lines with `err` from `@capture` or, if absent altogether, then all with `warn`. For this you have the make the full pass for `err` first, then look for `warn`.  A simple way

```
my @matched_string = grep { /\berr\b/ } @capture;
@matched_string = grep { /\bwarn\b/ } @capture  if not @matched_string;
```

But if you simply want all strings in `@capture` with either `err` or `warn` words in them, then

```
my @matched_string = grep { /\b(?:err|warn)\b/ } @capture;
```

Please clarify the purpose if the above guesses aren't right.

Comment: can i replace the above expression with @matched_string = (grep(/\berr\b||\bwarn\b/, @capture)

Comment: @SudhirMishra Well, yes -- but that will give you all strings in `@capture` that have _either_ `err` _or_ `warn` words in them.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @SudhirMishra  I added it to the answer, let me know if it isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Perform the assignment first then do the "or" as follows
#or combine the regex to achieve what you are trying to achieve:


use strict;
use warnings;

my @capture = "err=\"some value\"";
my  @matched_string;
if ((@matched_string = grep(/\berr\b/, @capture)) || (@matched_string =     grep(/\bwarn\b/, @capture)) ) {
   print "@matched_string";
}



#Another alternative (combining the regex)


use strict;
use warnings;

my @capture = "warn\"some value\"";

if ((my @matched_string = grep(/\b(err|warn)\b/, @capture))) {
   print "@matched_string";
}
```